# InAppPurchase issue with Invalid Identifiers

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am testing in App Purchase and followed so many tutorials , did same what they specified in tutorial , I set number of product identifiers for one app, only did not upload its binary but it is still saying Invalid Product Identifiers , I am checking after few hours and still getting same error.
The status of my product in iTunes Connect is "Ready to Submit".

What could be the issue ? Should I upload binary to apple and then reject it ??

Please help!
Thanks ...

Comment: the status in iTunes Connect is not relevant in the case of `inAppPurchase`. the `inAppPurchase` procedure is already fully working when you are in the test-period with it. when the tests ware great and fully worked, the final application will be working fine. if the tests was failed the fully application will be failed during the `inAppPurchase`. how did you set up the ProductID in the iTunes Connect and in your application?

Comment: I added placeholder for application with details and go to manage in app purchase , added few product identifier and named it as com.comapnayname.fengshui.rat

Answer (score 1):

[Here you have](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/) a list of things that can cause this error

Answer (score 0):

Are your contract, tax, and banking Information completed?

I had the same issue, and after I follow this [technical notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html), It will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue has been solved . Issue was because of jailbroken device . I tested on jailbroken device.
Here is the solution for jailbroken device ..Go to Cydia
Cydia - > All Packages - > AppSync - > Uninstall AppSync

And then Test it.